# Solo un registro con PHPMailer

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código que es para generar un correo con la clase PHPMailer, con los resultados de una consulta. Mi problema es que el email lo manda bien, pero solo me manda el último resultado. En la sentencia no tengo ningun filtro de ascendente, ni descendente, ni limit. Cuando yo ejecuto la consulta el resultado que me devuelve es el siguiente:

```
 - MONO XL: 1
 - Mono S: 22
 - GUANTE: 8
```

Esa es la lista que quiero que me devuelva a mi email. Pero en cambio solo me devuelve:

```
 - GUANTE: 8
```

Os dejo mi código por si me podeis ayudar

```
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
  $mail->Subject = 'EPIs';
  while($epis=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $epi = $epis['epi'];
    $cantidad = $epis['total'];
    /*echo "<ul>";
      echo"<li>".$epi." : ".$cantidad."</li>";
    echo "</ul>";*/
        $body = "Quedan escasas unidades de los siguientes epis en nuestros almacenes: <br>
                <ul>
                  <li>".$epi." : ".$cantidad."</li>
                </ul>

              ";
  }
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);
  $mail->AddAddress($email); // Cargamos el e-mail destinatario a la clase PHPMailer
  $mail->Send(); // Realiza el envío =)
  $mail->ClearAddresses(); // Limpia los "Address" cargados previamente para volver a cargar uno.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas sobreescribiendo la varibale `$body` deberias tenerlo asi dentro del `while`

```php
$body = "Quedan escasas unidades de los siguientes epis en nuestros almacenes: <br>";
$body .= " <ul>";

while($epis=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $epi = $epis['epi'];
    $cantidad = $epis['total'];
    $body .= "<li>".$epi." : ".$cantidad."</li>";
}
$body .= "</ul>";
```

Comment: Exacto! Eso era lo que me pasaba, ya funciona correctamente! Gracias!